# How to run a container on GitHub actions Windows agent?

Tags: github-actions, testcontainers, windows-container

It is known that "testcontainers" doesn't work on Windows 2019 ([issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2960)).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:247)
```

What is possible alternatives or workarounds for that, e.g. starting a custom service from an image on GitHub actions "windows-2019" agents?

For clarity, let's take a JMS broker (image `"symptoma/activemq:5.16.2"`) and try to start it so it is available in OS on port 12345: (`tcp://localhost:12345`)

How to start ActiveMQ on GitHub actions Windows agent (`runs-on: windows-2019`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per GitHub info on their [issues](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/904), Windows agents are not supported.
I'd incentivize you to pile on the request there so they revert the decision and bring support for Windows.